# How to optimise sample code for a very slow SOAP service?

Tags: java, android, xml, web-services, soap

This is a sample code of soap web Service. but it is so slow. How can I improve and optimize the code to speed up the response?

```
private class Query extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
   ProgressDialog PD = new ProgressDialog(Products.this);

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       PD.setMessage("plec...");
       PD.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
       PD.show();
   }

   @Override
   protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
       sp_cod_anbar = getSharedPreferences("cod", 0);
       String cod_and = sp_cod_anb.getString("cod", "0");
       boolean resul = true;
       final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
       final String URL = "";
       final String METHOD_NAME = "";
       final String SOAP_ACTION = "";
       SoapObject requste = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

       requste.addProperty("com", cod);
       requste.addProperty("cat", Id);

       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new                 SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
       envelope.dotNet = true;
       envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requste);
       HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
       androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
       androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
       try {
           androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
           Log.d("RESULT", "" + result);
           int cols = result.getPropertyCount();
           prgmNameList = new String[cols];
           prgmEm = new String[cols];
           prgmmo = new String[cols];
           prgmGht = new String[cols];
           prgmImages = new String[cols];

           for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
               Object objectResponse = (Object) result.getProperty(i);
               SoapObject r = (SoapObject) objectResponse;
               prgmNameList[i] =r.getProperty("Kala").toString();
               prgmEm [i] = r.getProperty("Em").toString();
               prgmmo [i] = r.getProperty("Mo").toString();
               prgmGht [i] = r.getProperty("Ght").toString();
               prgmImages [i] = r.getProperty("Ax").toString();


           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
           String err = (e.getMessage() == null) ? "SD Card failed" : e.getMessage();
           Log.e("sdcard-err2:", err);
           resul = false;
       }

       return resul;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

       if (result) {

           adapter = new MainListAdapter(Productst.this, prgmNameList, prgmEm ,prgmmo ,prgmGht ,prgmImages );
           listView_products.setAdapter(adapter);



           PD.dismiss();
       } else {
           PD.dismiss();
           Intent in = new Intent(Products.this, ErrorConnection.class);
           startActivity(in);


       }

   }    }
```

Comment: Questions for working code ... might go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Jägermeister I didn't now that such community exists. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. you can mark the debug flag to false
2. Instead of using
   `Object objectResponse = (Object) result.getProperty(i);<br>
    SoapObject r = (SoapObject) objectResponse;`

   use
   `SoapObject r = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(i);`